# Replacing the gmail account on my Mi android phone

Tags: factory-reset, google-account, xiaomi, formatting

My mother gave me her MI phone with android. It has her gmail account. I want to replace it with my gmail account. How can I do this?
I looked at Settings -> Accounts -> Google, but did not find there any way to replace the account.

Even better: is there a way to "format" the phone, so that I can start from a blank phone and directly enter my gmail account?

Comment: Why format? Simply factory reset the phone and start afresh

Comment: You can not change the account but remove it. You already were at the correct place, just select the Google account to be deleted and open the menu in the upper right corner. There you can delete the account.

Comment: @Robert When I go to Settings -> Accounts -> Google, I do not see the account name (maybe there is only a single account?). I see "My Account" title, then "Sign-in & Security", "Personal info & privacy", "Account Preferences"... 
In the upper-right corner menu I see "Clear app data", "Usage & Diagnostics" , "Oper source Licenses", "Show debug items", "Help & feedback"

Comment: You are in "Settings -> Google" not "Settings -> Accounts -> Google". When you see the synchronization settings of your Google account you are at the right location.

Comment: I did not find Settings->Accounts - I only found Settings - Other Accounts. There, I found Google, and Indeed I see the account the be deleted, but, I do not see any menu in the upper-right corner...

Comment: you can perform a factory reset and can use  it as a fresh device. Goto settings->Additional Settings->Backup and reset. Then tap reset. If you had added mi account attached, sometimes it maybe required. You haven't added your device name and miui version in question. There's another option to factory reset is from recovery mode. Settings->about device it loads updater page, and on top right tap on three dots and select reboot to recovery. And on recovery, you can wipe completely. If your bootloader is locked, you cannot goto recovery. so you can do the first step.

Answer (score 1):

My phone is mi5 pro running MIUI 9.5 Android 7
In the settings menu go to Sync > scroll down > click add account > enter your Google account

Step 2 is to delete the existing mothers account. Sync > Google > select moms account > gear icon on the bottom > remove account. [image]